# Automatic answer TTY prompt with script

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, tty

I see many posts about answering prompt with

> echo 'yes' | your_script

however what if the prompt was via TTY so doing something like above result in an exception

`The program is attempting to read user input, but stdin is being piped from some other source (not a TTY).`

From what I been reading it seems like using TTY to prompt is to increase security. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Interesting... I get no exception when I try `echo 'a' | read; echo $REPLY`, neither in TTY nor in `xterm`, but also no output.

Comment: Yes, you should use an instrumentation program like `expect`. For simple cases, you can use just `script(1)`: `{ sleep .1; echo yes; } | script /dev/null -qc your_sript`

Comment: @Quasímodo how do you know that that script is using just `read` as in your example? (which btw is broken, that will NOT set `$REPLY`, and will not echo `a`).

Comment: @mosvy Yeah, I don't, just tried to reproduce the behavior. I missed that the `read` part is run in a subshell, so `$REPLY` will be empty. `echo 'a' | { read; echo $REPLY; }` however does output `a`.